# Delete consecutive ROWs EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, rows

My data is in column A and i want to remove all consecutive rows like in column B.
code

```
  If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value Then
    Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete shift:=xlUp
  End If
```

i wrote the script but i dont know how to put it in a loop.. any help thanks.

[image]

Comment: Typically, deleting rows is best accomplished by starting at the bottom and moving toward the top. Are you sure you want to loop back to the first row?

Comment: It doesnt mater how i do it but i want to endup with the results as shown in column "B"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since removing rows is quite time-consuming, the best approach for this task is to collect all the rows to be deleted into a single object of `Range` class by using `Union` function and then delete all of them with a single operation.

Below is the code presenting how to do that:

```
Sub deleteConsecutiveRows()
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim row As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------


    Set wks = Excel.ActiveSheet


    With wks
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

        For row = 2 To lastRow
            If .Cells(row, 1).Value = .Cells(row - 1, 1).Value Then

                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = .Rows(row)
                Else
                    Set rng = Excel.Union(rng, .Rows(row))
                End If

            End If
        Next row

    End With


    'In order to avoid Run-time error check if [rng] range is not empty, before removing it.
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Call rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, deleting rows is best accomplished by starting at the bottom and moving toward the top. This avoids 'skipping' a row when you delete is and the rows are shifted up.

```
Dim rw As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(rw, 1).Value = .Cells(rw - 1, 1).Value Then _
            .Rows(rw).Delete
    Next rw
End With
```

Again, typically a column of data will have a column header label that you would not want to involve in the deletion process. However, as long as the label (if there is one) does not match the cell value in row 2 this should not be a problem.